# createQueryBuilder leftJoin using Doctrine and Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

This code doesn't work. Can anybody help me? The code is:

```
class ResultRepository extends EntityRepository
{
     public function findAllByUserResultVote($id_vote)
     {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
           //associating tables...
           ->leftJoin('r.user' , 'u')
           ->leftJoin('r.answer' , 'a')
           ->leftJoin('r.vote' , 'v')

           //Where idVote (Table result) == id (Table vote)
           ->where('r.idVote = :idVote')
           ->setParameter('idVote', $id_vote)
           ->getQuery();
        return $query->getResult();
     }
}
```

I have an entity User, Answer, Vote, Result.

And I have 4 tables:
User: id (primary), name, ...
Vote: id (primary), question, ...
Answer: id (primary), idVote, answer ...
Result: id (primary), idUser (id table user), idVote (id table vote), idAnswer (id table answer), ...

-----**Edit**----
Thanks for the answer, but that is not what I do.
Result also is a table. And this only contains id and I need return for example:
**Instead of:** 1, 6, 5, 3
**This:** 1, u.name, v.question, a.answer

Comment: I don't think you need all of the `->where('r.idUser = u.id')` parts as the joins are already made in your schema so it knows where to do it. Also, do you have actual fields called `idUser`, `idAnswer` or `idVote`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function findAllByUserResultVote($idVote)
 {
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')

    // From your question, it looks like you only want ids
       ->select('r.id, u.name, v.question, a.answer')

    // join with Vote Entity
       ->leftJoin('r.vote' , 'v')
    // join with User Entity
       ->leftJoin('r.user' , 'u')
    // join with Answer Entity
       ->leftJoin('r.answer' , 'a')

    // where id is same as $idVote
       ->andWhere('v.id = :id_vote')
       ->setParameter('id_vote', $idVote);

    return $queryBuilder
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've just edited because I think I did not explain clearly. I would need return 1, u.name, v.question, a.answer instead of 1, 6, 5, 3...

Comment: @Zarlok There you go!